# In jasmine + karmajs, using global await make the test fail

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine

Using karma and jasmine...

I have a module using a global await:

```
import ...

const data = await fetch()...
```

And a test using it:

```
import ...
describe() ...
```

It seems that jasmine complain about it:

```
An error was thrown in afterAll
  Error: 'describe' should only be used in 'describe' function in node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js (line 1811)
```

Any idea if my analysis is correct?
Any idea on how to configure karma to make that work?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late reply, but YES I am getting this too. My solution was to take the async call out of the global context of the module I was loading and run it in the `beforeAll` method of the test suite. I'm aware this might not be a solution for everyone though.